# Hibernate & Spring - org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, configuration

i'm new in Spring and tried to include a working hibernate project into a spring environment. The projects work solo perfectly, but not in combination. First I tried to execute my Hibernate test (last code snippet) in the main before SpringApplikation.run() but it was executed twice. Then I read that you have to mark a class as @Component if I want to get an instantiation of it when running the app - without success. Any suggestions how to solve this? (:

this is my console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

17:02:01.782 [restartedMain] INFO  d.s.k.KeyCloakTutorial - Starting KeyCloakTutorial on XXX with PID 16765 (/home/user/test_environment/slackspace-angular2-spring-keycloak/backend/target/classes started by mario in /home/user/test_environment/slackspace-angular2-spring-keycloak/backend)
17:02:01.784 [restartedMain] INFO  d.s.k.KeyCloakTutorial - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
17:02:01.812 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.restart.ChangeableUrls - The Class-Path manifest attribute in /home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/home/user/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
17:02:01.813 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
17:02:01.813 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
17:02:02.621 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
17:02:02.628 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8000"]
17:02:02.628 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
17:02:02.628 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
17:02:02.692 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
17:02:02.692 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 879 ms
17:02:02.801 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
17:02:02.842 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping - Adding welcome page: ServletContext resource [/index.html]
17:02:02.896 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer - LiveReload server is running on port 35729
------------------------------------------------------
Hibernate wird initialisiert
17:02:02.950 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
17:02:03.032 [restartedMain] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.deprecation - HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
17:02:03.189 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
17:02:03.248 [restartedMain] WARN  o.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
17:02:03.253 [restartedMain] INFO  o.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres]
17:02:03.253 [restartedMain] INFO  o.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
17:02:03.253 [restartedMain] INFO  o.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling - HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
17:02:03.255 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.j.c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
17:02:03.298 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Hibernate: drop table if exists NOTIFICATION cascade
17:02:03.703 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@68a556ca] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1
17:02:03.712 [restartedMain] INFO  org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@158e367f] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table NOTIFICATION (ID int8 not null, channel varchar(255), message varchar(1024) not null, name varchar(64), trigger varchar(64) not null, primary key (ID))
17:02:03.737 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate wurde initialisiert
------------------------------------------------------
de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.Notification@c76354a
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
17:02:03.784 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
17:02:03.792 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
17:02:03.794 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1] value by reflection : [class de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.Notification.id] setter of de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.Notification.id
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5124)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:626)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:614)
    at de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.NotificationDao.create(NotificationDao.java:19)
    at de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.init.DatabaseStarter.init(DatabaseStarter.java:24)
    at de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.init.DatabaseStarter.contextRefreshedEvent(DatabaseStarter.java:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:305)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:153)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.KeyCloakTutorial.main(KeyCloakTutorial.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.Notification.id to de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification.Notification
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterFieldImpl.set(SetterFieldImpl.java:41)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
17:02:03.796 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

the notification-class:

```
package de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.notification;

import javax.persistence.*;

import de.slackspace.keycloaktutorial.Channel;

@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTIFICATION")
public class Notification {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=64, nullable=true)
    private String name;

    @Column(length=64, nullable=false)
    private String trigger;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Channel channel;

    @Column(length=1024, nullable=false)
    private String message;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getTrigger() {
        return trigger;
    }

    public void setTrigger(String trigger) {
        this.trigger = trigger;
    }

    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(Channel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

the dao:

```
public class NotificationDao {

    public void create(Session session, String name, String trigger, String channel, String message) {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.setName(name);
        notification.setTrigger(trigger);
        notification.setChannel(Channel.valueOf(channel.toUpperCase()));
        notification.setMessage(message);   
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(notification);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.refresh(notification);
    }

}
```

my try to initialize hibernate:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseStarter {

    @EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        HibernateConfigurator hibernateConfigurator = new HibernateConfigurator();
        Session session = hibernateConfigurator.getSession();

        NotificationDao notificationDao = new NotificationDao();
        notificationDao.create(session, "test_name", "test_trigger", "EMAIL", "test_message");
    }

}
```

Thanks for help! (=

Edit: I have a solution. It's savage and cruel, but it's working. I switched from Hibernate to JPA and have no trouble anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL auto-increment is handled using the SERIAL pseudo type and this SERIAL pseudo type creates a sequence. Sequences are similar, but not identical, to the AUTO_INCREMENT concept in MySQL. change code as below

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

Comment: I tried it and looked for other solutions like "GenerationType.AUTO" also - still the same error :(